# How to pass array elements as parameter in function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, variadic-functions

I have got a function like this:

```
void foo(int count, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, count);
  // Do Somethings...
  va_end(args);
}
```

I want to pass array elements as parameter in `foo` function like this:

```
void bar(int n, int array[])
{
  // I want to pass array elements as parameter like this:
  foo(n, array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], ..... array[n]);
}
```

Using `bar` function:

```
int main()
{
  bar(7, std::initializer_list<int>({ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }));

  return 0;
}
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: [Ellipsis (and why to avoid them)](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/714-ellipsis-and-why-to-avoid-them/)

Comment: Do you want to pass an *array* or an `std::initializer_list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what are the array values at compile-time, you can use `std::index_sequences` and a bit of template machinery to do that in C++14.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void foo(std::size_t count, Args... args) {
    int _[] = { 0, (std::cout << args << std::endl, 0)... };
    (void)_;
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... I, typename T>
void bar(std::index_sequence<I...>, T(&array)[N]) {
    foo(N, array[I]...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
void bar(T(&array)[N]) {
    bar(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, array);
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    bar(array);
}
```

I assumed `array` is an array and not a `std::initializer_list`. The question was a bit confusing on this point.

Note that the following works as well with the code above:

```
void foo(std::size_t count, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    // do something...
    va_end(args);
}
```